# Is it possible to add another Unicode character for "at sign" without changing any code in the back-end of all the email providers?

Tags: email, parsing, unicode

So lets say for some reason we wanted to add another Unicode character for at sign, and use it instead of @ in all the email providers

Now i have three questions:

1. How do email providers parse the email, do they actually parse the written email until they see a @ and they have hard-coded the @ symbol's Unicode in the parser?
2. Do different service providers have different email parser with different standards or is there a standard type of parser library that every email provider use?
3. Will it be possible to add another at sign symbol and use it in emails without having to make changes in all the email provider's code?

Comment: This is way too broad, and unclear why you are asking this. Replacing SMTP with something else entirely is not feasible, and replacing it with *almost* the same thing would make no sense at all.

Comment: The first fallacy here is assuming that the email infrastructure is owned and operated by a small and contollable group of "email providers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, e-mail addresses are parsed using a hard-wired `@` character. After almost fifty years of e-mail, there are literally millions of e-mail handling programs, and they all use this same syntax. So you're not going to be able to change this convention, and your second and third questions are moot.

Answer (score 0):

E-mail addresses are parsed by tens of different kind of softwares, not just "email server" software inside "e-mail providers".  Even things as trivial as client-side javascript highlighting  for an e-mail field - of which there are easly tens of thousands around, would have to adapt.

An "@" is not a character class by itself - so, even if it were an unique "unicode character class" for "Unicode Separator", whou would ever have written code that would check for the *character class* of the separator? Have you ever done that, even for filtering punctuation out? (A real use case for the unicode classification of characters, and even them, this sees little use in real-world code).

Now, of course, you are free to write *email* client code that would present the "@" as anything else when rendering e-mail data to the users. Internally, if this software would not use "@", even for its own uses, it would not work with anything else in the World -  from antivirus software to text-based templates.

And finally, such a change would hardly have to do with "unicode" itself - Unicode can standardize characters - but the e-mail protocol is a separate thing - normally the series of documents kept as "RFC"s is what mandate various internet protocols, including IMAP, POP and SMTP-  the three protocols that are used to enable e-mail to work. Even if new RFCs for all these would be published with a new character accept in place of "@", it would likely take more than a decade until all software around, as detailed above, would be compliant enough to enable it to be used. (And yes, *all* of it would have to be changed)